# Databound FormView with DropDownList Questions

Tags: c#, asp.net, ddl, formview

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Eliminate the `FormView’s` default edit link button.
2. Display the `FormView` in edit mode on `Page_Load` with current data and additional DDL data selections.

Currently I have the following to bind the DDL to the current database value based upon `id = x` etc:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("xxx") %>' 
DataSourceID="xxx"
DataTextField="xxx"
DataValueField="xxx"
ondatabound="DropDownList1_DataBound">
```

Via C# code I do this to add additional DDL list items for selection: (which is a waste of my energy because the data is already in the database!)

```
protected void DropDownList1 _DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("DropDownList1");
     DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("0 - 1 km/h", "0"));
     DropDownList1.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("2 - 5 km/h", "1"));
     DropDownList1.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem("6 - 11 km/h", "2"));
     DropDownList1.Items.Insert(4, new ListItem("12 - 19 km/h", "3"));
     DropDownList1.Items.Insert(5, new ListItem("20 - 28 km/h", "4"));
}
```

There has got to be a better way!

Comment: Does the `DropDownList1` not get those results from the `DataSource` you have linked?  Why do you have to populate it manually?

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to populate the `DropDownList` dynamically from the database?  If that is the case, why are you adding them manually, and where is the code to pull them from the DB?  On Stackoverflow **MORE** information is always better :)

Comment: Hi Brian - The DDL does contain a single data item from a query to the datasource. The items I am adding manually are an additional dataset that I'd like added to the DDL. As such the user can see thier original record item AND perhaps select a new item (for record update) via the additional DDL items (those which I've manually added). The data that I'm adding manually exists but I am not sure how to bind it to the DDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know exactly how you are connecting to the database but if you are using datacontext linq to sql is a good way to do it. Your 'ddl' will have an onLoad event and you can use a query in the code behind. For example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
                  onLoad="DropDownList1_Load"
                  AutoPostBack="true" />
```

And then in the code behind:

```
protected void DropDownList1_Load(object sender, EventARgs e)
{
    YourDataContext db = new YourDataContext();
    var qry = from a in db.table1
              select a;
    foreach(var itm in qry)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(itm.speedRange.ToString(), itm.id.ToString()));
     db.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ratan - You've given me some ideas!

Comment: you're welcome. Would appreciate a vote up or marked as answer.